# How to make this table page-breakable?

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I currently have a table that has grown a bit and no longer fits its intended space. Since I expect this table to keep growing in the future, I need to make it page-breakable while keeping its current style. There are many posts out there on how to get page-breakable tables, but I have not been able to use any of the solutions I have found because I either got errors I could not wrap my head around, or the final output did not look as intended.

I share below a MWE which shows my current (non-breakable) table as well as a screenshot of the output it produces. What the MWE does is create a list environment which I then invoke whenever necessary. My goal is **to replicate this output but making sure that the table will correctly break (rather than jump) whenever it reaches a page break**.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rl}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
    \parbox[t]{1.75cm}{#1\raggedleft}&\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.75cm}{\strut%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par\strut}%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

\begin{entrylist}

  \entry
    {XXXX}
    {Fancy stuff 1}
    {Fancy stuff 1}
    {Fancy stuff 1}

  \entry
    {YYYY}
    {Fancy stuff 2}
    {Fancy stuff 2}
    {Fancy stuff 2}

  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you all very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not encapsulate the whole stuff into tabular environment. You can define format of each `\entry` by your macros. The `\smallskip` after `\hbox` is page-breakable, of course.

```
\newdimen\colsep \colsep=1em
\def\topbox#1#2{\vtop{\parindent=0pt \hsize=\dimexpr#1\relax #2}}
\def\entry#1#2#3#4{\par
   \hbox{\topbox{1.75cm}{#1\raggedleft}\kern\colsep
         \topbox{\hsize-2\colsep-1.75cm}{{\bf#2}\hfill {\footnotesize#3}\endgraf#4\strut}}
   \smallskip
}

  \entry
    {XXXX}
    {Fancy stuff 1}
    {Fancy stuff 1}
    {Fancy stuff 1}

  \entry
    {YYYY}
    {Fancy stuff 2}
    {Fancy stuff 2}
    {Fancy stuff 2}

  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer: it provides a very elegant solution to the problem at hand. Hence, I have decided to accept it. However, I am not entirely sure I should do this, since Mico's and egreg's answers do answer my specific question while yours does not answer it but provides a better approach to the problem instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to do is

- load the `longtable` package and issue the instructions `\setlength\LTleft{0pt}` and `\setlength\LTright{0pt}` in the preamble and
- replace `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}` with `\begin{longtable}` and `\end{tabular*}` with `\end{longtable}` in the definition of the `entrylist` environment.

Optionally, you could delete the `\noindent` directive at the start of the definition of the `entrylist` environment.

See section 5, entitled "Adjustment", of `longtable` user guide for more information about what the length parameters `\LTleft` and `\LTright` do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please, see my comment under wipet's answer to see why I have accepted his/her answer (despite my doubts on what I should do).

Answer (score 1):

Use `longtable`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for nonsense text
\usepackage{showframe} % for showing the page boundaries

\newlength{\entrylistwidth}
\setlength{\entrylistwidth}{1.75cm}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{longtable}{
    @{}
    w{l}{\entrylistwidth}
    p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\entrylistwidth}
    @{}
  }
}{\end{longtable}}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1 & \textbf{#2}\hfill{\footnotesize #3\par}#4\\\noalign{\vspace{\parsep}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{entrylist}

  \entry
    {XXXX}
    {Fancy stuff 1}
    {Fancy stuff 1}
    {\lipsum[1][1-3]}

  \entry
    {YYYY}
    {Fancy stuff 2}
    {Fancy stuff 2}
    {\lipsum[2][1-3]}

  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
  \entry
    {ZZZZ}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {Fancy stuff 3}
    {\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is almost what I need: the only problem is that the contents of the left column (i.e., "XXXX", "YYYY", "ZZZZ") should be left ragged left. I can't find a way to tweak your code such that they are ragged left. Any hint?

Comment: @Hector If you have longer entries for the first column that should be split across lines, change `w{l}{\entrylistwidth}` into `>{\raggedright}p{\entrylistwidth}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your further comment. Please, see my comment under wipet's answer to see why I have accepted his/her answer (despite my doubts on what I should do).

Comment: @Hector I'd say that mixing plain TeX style with LaTeX is not the best idea, if you don't know the subtleties. Anyway, the choice is yours.